# Erasing data from array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My data looks like this:

```
{
"schoolPersonal": [
    {
        "student": {
            "Name": "John",
            "Lastname": "Smith"
        }
    },
    {
        "student": {
            "Name": "Peter",
            "Lastname": "Parker"
        }
    },
    {
        "professor": {
            "Name": "Stephen",
            "Lastname": "Strange"
        }
    },
    {
        "professor": {
            "Name": "Steven",
            "Lastname": "Rogers"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I want to erase professor Stephen Strange so I have this code but isn't working:

```
school.findOneAndUpdate({ id: schoolId }, { $pull: { schoolPersonal: { professor: { Name: "Stephen" }}}}, { useFindAndModify: false }, function(err, professor)
```

I don't know if there is another way to work around what I'm trying to do here

Answer (score 0):

You should try deleteOne method. Change callback logic.

```
collection.deleteOne({ "professor": {
            "Name": "Stephen",
            "Lastname": "Strange"
        }}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.send(err);
  } else {
    res.send(result);
  }
})
```